# XSLT - How to set correct language in a choos

Tags: xslt, metadata, dita

I'm using XSLT Dita OT to generat PDF files.
For the publicationproces its possible to generate a translation files in EN, FR, DE, IT. Now i used the code as below to manage my output.

I this case the language is a metadata and thats why i use the "*@ attribute*"

But after publishing my code it isn't working. can someone help me with this.

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@xml:lang = 'EN'">
                <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="languagecontainer" top="25mm">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="languageblock">ENGLISH</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:when>             
                <xsl:when test="@xml:lang = 'FR'">
                <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="languagecontainer" top="55mm">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="languageblock">FRANÇAIS</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@xml:lang = 'DE'">
                    <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="languagecontainer" top="85mm">
                        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="languageblock">DEUTSCH</fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </xsl:when>    
                <xsl:when test="@xml:lang = 'IT'">
                <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="languagecontainer" top="115mm">
                     <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="languageblock">ITALIANO</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@xml:lang = 'ES'">
                <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="languagecontainer" top="145mm">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="languageblock">ESPAÑOL</fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>no result</xsl:text>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about XSLT, but you're going to want to update your answer to say something less vague than it isn't working.

Comment: How can we possibly know why your code isn't working when you don't show the input and don't tell us either the expected output or the actual output? There is nothing obviously wrong with the code snippet you have shown us.

Comment: Your code is vastly more verbose than it needs to be, but you should probably find why it isn't working before you try and refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be useful to insert debug `<xsl:message>` instruction before the `<xsl:choose>` to analyze your problem.

```
<xsl:message select="'context=',."/>
<xsl:message select="'@xml:lang=',@xml:lang"/>
```

If the context is not a element, referencing `@xml:lang` is no meaning. Or if `@xml:lang` is not the expected one ('FR', 'DE' ,'IT' ,'ES'), you should correct your template to match the actual `@xml:lang` attribute value.